# MP4Box: Concat working on OSX but not Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, macos, video, mp4box

the following code

`MP4Box -force-cat -add split0.mp4 -cat split1.mp4 -cat split2.mp4 -cat split3.mp4 -new output.mp4`

works perfectly on my OSX installation of MP4Box, but fails on an Ubuntu EC2 throwing these warnings

`WARNING: Concatenating track ID 1 with different PPS - result file might be broken`

Even though the PPS is definitely the same (the same files are used for the OSX run). Output.mp4 is a broken mp4 file in the linux version. The version is up to date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apt-get version of MP4Box is not up to date. Had to build from the .deb package, available here wget http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/release/0.6.1/gpac_0.6.1_amd64.deb
and follow these instructions https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2011/04/20/compiling-gpac-on-ubuntu/